# Do continuous curves (considered as a subset or subspace) in $\mathbb{R}^2$ contain open sets?

Tags: general-topology

The first part of my question is if we consider a continuous curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ does it contain any open sets
?

My attempt at answering this question is as follows:

Basic open sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are disks with the boundary removed and so because a continuous curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a one-dimensional object in a two-dimensional space, it can't contain any two-dimensional objects, and so a continuous curve considered as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ has no open sets.

The next part of the question is can continuous curves in $\mathbb{R}^2$ be subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

I know that the subspace topology of the natural numbers, as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$, is the discrete topology and so is there a similar subspace topology where instead the elements of the subspace topology vary continuously?

In a discrete topology every set is defined to be open, do we assert something similar for continuous curves in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

As an example, consider the set $A=\{(x,x^2):x\in\mathbb{R}\}$, which is a line of a parabola in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Can we considered this line as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$? If so, what do the open sets of $A$ look like?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: "Open sets in $\mathbb R^2$ are unit disks with the boundary removed" is incorrect. Certainly not every open set is of that form.

Comment: Thank you! I'll go ahead and edit that.

Comment: To add on to what Ittay Weiss said: open disks *are* open sets in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ (with the standard topology).  But you can have other open sets that are not open disks.  BUT open disks form a *basis* for the standard topology.  What this means is that every open set in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ with the standard topology can be expressed as an arbitrary union of open disks.  So you *can* have open sets that are not strictly open disks, but every open set can be expressed as a union of open disks.

Comment: Thank you for emphasizing this fact. I went ahead and edited my question. I hope that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any non-empty subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ can be thought of as a subspace when we equip it with the subspace topology.  Specifically, a set is open in $A$ (i.e., with respect to the subspace topology of $A$) if it is equal to an open set in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ intersected with $A$.

So if you take all of the open sets in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, and intersect each of them with $A$, you get the open sets in $A$ (i.e., open with respect to the subspace topology).

To get some intuition, draw a random curve and then draw an open ball somewhere else that intersects with a part of the curve.  The intersection will be the part of the curve that is contained in the open ball, and this is considered an "open" set in the curve.

Comment: I see, thank you for clearing that up for me. Also, does my logic for answering whether the continuous curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ considered as a subset make sense with regards to it containing no open sets?

Comment: @ShantDanielian Yes, I agree with you that the graph of a continuous function (i.e., the set of coordinates $\{ (x, f(x) \}$ for a continuous function $f$) is not itself open, and does not contain any open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.  BUT when viewed as a **subspace**, it *is* open in the subspace topology, and furthermore any open set of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ intersected with the curve will result in a set that is contained in the continuous function and is open.  But it is open with respect to the subspace topology.

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I was just thinking. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4):

I don't quite understand all of your questions, but the answer to "can the image of a continuous curve contain open sets?" is yes, it can. There exist (well-known) space-filling curves.